# Determinant of an inequality

Tags: inequality

$ax^2 + bx + c > 0$ is an inequality where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers. If I know that atleast one real solution for $x$ exists, does this mean that the determinant of the inequality (i.e, $b^2 - 4ac$) must be greater than or equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: it depends on sign of a

Comment: This is called discriminant, not determinant.

Comment: @Hrishikesh Venkataraman When you say "one solution", do you mean a solution of the inequality?. This is confusing some people because the solutions of inequalities are usually intervals.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Counterexample: $x^2+1$ is always positive, so every real $x$ is a solution of the inequality. However $b^2-4ac=-4<0$.

Comment: It does not have a real root and that is why discriminant is negative.

Comment: @Math Lover The OP does not say there is a root, but that the **inequality** has a solution. Or at least that is my interpretation.

Comment: oh ok,. Discriminant $\ge 0$ comment threw me off I guess.

Comment: @Miguel "one real solution for $x$ exists" strongly implies there is one real root.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Not for me. Then the inequality would not appear in the problem at all. Anyway let us see if the OP is able to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The given function $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ is always strictly positive.

That means, $f(x)$ never touch or going accross through $X$- axis.

So, this is meaningless to say $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$ have a root.